# Seleccionar un solo "checkbox" y luego hacer un calculo

Tags: php, html, css

estoy introduciéndome al mundo de la Programacion Web, y en uno de los proyectos que estoy realizando a traves del curso, me he conseguido con la siguiente duda, de la que he investigado pero no logro dar con lo que de verdad busco.

Consiste en un pagina HTML donde pido ingresar: Nombre, Apellido, Horas Trabajadas y mediante un Checkbox pedir que si trabaja en el turno "Diurno" o "Nocturno". En el PHP donde hago los calculos, tengo que cada hora trabajada se pagara a 12 y si es de noche a 15.

```css
/* Hoja de Estilos */

#titulo{
 
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 background-color: #999999;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.valor{

 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Ingresar Usuario</title>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css">

<body>

 <form action="ingresar.php" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <table align="center">
   <h1 align="center" id="titulo">Ingrese sus Datos</h1>
   <tr align="center">
    <td class="valor">Nombre</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="nombre" size="20" placeholder="Agustin" required></td>
   </tr>
   <tr align="center">
    <td class="valor">Apellido</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="apellido" size="20" placeholder="Guanipa" required></td>
   </tr>
   <tr align="center">
    <td class="valor">Horas de Trabajo</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="hora" size="20" placeholder="0..100" required ></td>
   </tr>
   <tr align="center">
    <td class="valor">Turno</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="o1">Diurno</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align="center">
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="o2">Nocturno</td>
   </tr>
   <tr align="center">
    <td><input type="submit" value="Calcular"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**El problema viene** que quiero que solo se pueda seleccionar un checkbox, segun lo que investigue se hace mediante el type="radio" y colocando el mismo name. En el programa los pongo con diferente name "o1" y "o2". Para en el PHP poder hacer los calculos segun la opcion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Ingresar Usuario

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_GET['apellido'];
    $hora = $_GET['hora'];
    $o1 = $_GET['o1'];
    $o2 = $_GET['o2'];

    if ($o1) {
        $salario = $hora * 12;
    }elseif ($o2) {
        $salario = $hora * 15;
    }

?>

<p align="center" id="titulo">Recibo</p>

<p align="center" class="valor">

    <?php 

        echo "<br><b>Nombre: </b>".$nombre; echo "</br>";
        echo "<br><b>Apellido: </b>".$apellido; echo "</br>";
        echo "<br><b>Horas de Trabajo: </b>".$hora; echo "</br>";
        echo "<br><b>Salario a Pagar: </b>".$salario; echo " Bs.</br>";

    ?>

</p>
```

Seguramente hay una forma de hacer esto diferente, y poder seleccionar un checkbox y que haga correctamente el calculo segun la opcion que le ordene.

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar el mismo name, pero distinto value

```
<input type="radio" name="turno" value="dia">
<input type="radio" name="turno" value="noche">
```

Y en PHP has de comprobar el value de la variable $_GET['turno']

Comment: Bien esto me funciono correctamente, pero no entiendo la parte para corregir en PHP. Al hacer los calculos siempre lo hace con el de dia... Como puedo arreglarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Si le agregas esto a tu form:

```
<form id = "myForm" action="ingresar.php" method="get"...
```

Y añades Jquery 3.1 + este script:

```
$("form input:checkbox").change(function(){

    var $box = $(this); 

    $box.parents('#myForm').find(':checkbox').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });

    $box.prop("checked", true);        
});
```

Todo funciona como quieres.